# Textbox Field Name in access

Tags: ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

Got this error **#Name?** on my text-box field..my Field Name in my design View a same as the One in my Control Source property text-box but I'm not sure why i still got this error..

Can someone shares some lights here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that the control source is not a valid source. For example, the control source could be `State` when the actual data source is called `State1`. Although it is hard to understand what you are trying to say here:

> my Field Name in my design View a same as the One in my Control Source property text-box

If you mean the source is called `State` and the actual name of the textbox is also `State`, there's your problem. Rename the textbox something like `txtState` and the problem will be solved (in access especially, I always ensure I use Hungarian Notation).